# Why there is no notion ´bijective´ regarding morphism of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, morphism, ringed-spaces

Morphism of schemes is defined as morphism between ringed spaces, and the morphism is not a map　(pair of maps), so we cannnot define notion of bijectivity of morphism in the category of schemes, is my understanding correct？

Comment: You can define any notion you want, the question is what properties do you want it to satisfy?

Comment: I want to know is it usual to say 'bijectivity of morphism between schemes', and if so, in what kind of meaning we use the term.

Comment: Then I would say it is not usual, but if it had to mean anything it would be what's in @asdq's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that a morphism of schemes is bijective if its underlying map of topological spaces has that property.